# Having trouble with a mock object unit test

Tags: java, eclipse, easymock

I'm toying with mock objects and I'm having trouble setting up a unit test that checks if a list is being properly sorted. The conceit of this is that I'm mocking a clock, but simply using the times() method isn't working. The list should be in ascending order, but getting the first index simply returns whatever value was set last.

For reference, here is a working mock test that tests the clock being set at midnight:

```
@Test
public void shouldSetAtMidnight() {
    expect(mock.instant()).andReturn(Instant.from(this.midnight));

    expect(mock.getZone()).andReturn(this.timeZone);

    replay(mock);

    this.st.setDesiredValue(72);
    SetPoint[] sched = this.st.getSchedule();

    verify(mock);

    assertEquals(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, sched[0].getScheduledTime());
}
```

Here, setting the desired value is only important in that it adds a SetPoint to the array (setDesiredValue creates a SetPoint which has an int and a LocalTime). This is where I'm having difficulty:

```
@Test
public void shouldOrderTwoSetPointsAddedOutOfOrder() {
    expect(mock.instant()).andReturn(Instant.from(this.midnight)).times(2);

    expect(mock.getZone()).andReturn(this.timeZone).times(2);

    replay(mock);

    this.st.setDesiredValue(73);
    this.st.setDesiredValue(71);
    SetPoint[] schedule = this.st.getSchedule();

    verify(mock);

    assertEquals(71, schedule[0].getTemp());
}
```

setDesiredValue is supposed to associate an int value with a LocalTime, which in this case should be midnight. It then adds a SetPoint with those characteristics to the list and calls Collection's sort() method to sort them from lowest to highest. Now, I'm assuming that my problem here is that I'm associating two values with the exact same time despite calling times(2) for both expects, but I just recently started with mock objects and just don't have the knowledge of them to know where to go from here. Running this test returns 73 instead of 71.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. When you say `.andReturn(Instant.from(this.midnight)).times(2)`, the exact value passed to `.andReturn` is repeated twice.

You could do `.andReturn(Instant.from(this.midnight)).andReturn(Instant.from(this.midnight))`, which will give you two instants. But as a general rule, this is very bad form for a unit test. `Instant.from(this.midnight)` comes from outside the test, so you can't predict if calling this function twice will result in the same value or different values, making the test non-deterministic. Okay for an integration test, not okay for a unit tests, where you would be using mocks. It is better to use a real number, like `.andReturn(Instant.fromEpochSecond(10)).andReturn(Instant.fromEpochSecond(15))`.

You're not providing a whole lot of details about `st` and any reasons why you think the test should not return 73 instead of 71.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solved my problem completely.